# Why the query scans 8x times the documents it finds - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I've got 50 documents (for trial purposes) more or less like this one:

```
  "_id" : ObjectId("5461c8f0426f727f16010000"),
    "f" : [ 
        {
            "t" : "ry",
            "v" : 1972
        }, 
        {
            "t" : "g",
            "v" : [ 
                "Crime", 
                "Drama"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "t" : "ml",
            "v" : "English"
        }, 
        {
            "t" : "k",
            "v" : "movie"
        }, 
        {
            "t" : "ai",
            "v" : 972353
        }, 
        {
            "t" : "ec",
            "v" : 46
        }, 
        {
            "t" : "rel",
            "v" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

I made the following index:

```
{
    "f.t" : 1,
    "f.v" : 1
}
```

So I make the following query:

```
db.items.find( 
    {
        "$and": [
            {"f": {$elemMatch: {"t": "ry", "v": {$gt: 1980, $lt: 2000}}}},
            {"f": {$elemMatch: {"t": "g", "v": {$in: ["Drama"]}}}},
                        {"f": {$elemMatch: {"t": "k", "v": "movie"}}}
        ]
    }

).explain()
```

Explain document:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor f.t_1_f.v_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 6,
    "nscannedObjects" : 50,
    "nscanned" : 50,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 50,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 50,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "f.t" : [ 
            [ 
                "k", 
                "k"
            ]
        ],
        "f.v" : [ 
            [ 
                "movie", 
                "movie"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "b009115.mongolab.com:42700",
    "filterSet" : false,
    "stats" : {
        "type" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
        "works" : 51,
        "yields" : 0,
        "unyields" : 0,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "advanced" : 6,
        "needTime" : 44,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "children" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "FETCH",
                "works" : 51,
                "yields" : 0,
                "unyields" : 0,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "advanced" : 6,
                "needTime" : 44,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "forcedFetches" : 0,
                "matchTested" : 6,
                "children" : [ 
                    {
                        "type" : "IXSCAN",
                        "works" : 51,
                        "yields" : 0,
                        "unyields" : 0,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "advanced" : 50,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needFetch" : 0,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "keyPattern" : "{ f.t: 1.0, f.v: 1.0 }",
                        "isMultiKey" : 1,
                        "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['f.t']: [\"k\", \"k\"], field #1['f.v']: [\"movie\", \"movie\"]",
                        "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                        "dupsTested" : 50,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                        "matchTested" : 0,
                        "keysExamined" : 50,
                        "children" : []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As I see, it has scanned all documents (50) when only six are the matched documents. Why the scanned/matched document ratio is so poor (is it?). Is there a better way to improve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not "documents" it's "Objects" as is stated, but you would not be the first person to not fully understand the `.explain()` output.

Put simply, you have as part of your index an "array" element (actually the maximum "two" allowed), which means that your index is what we call "MultiKey". This means in very basic terms that the "compounded" index has "every possible combination" of the values that are specified within.

So a "very basic" view of indexed data might look like this:

```js
{ "f.t": "ry", "f.v": 1972 },
{ "f.t": "g",  "f.v": "Crime" },
{ "f.t": "g",  "f.v": "Drama" }
```

In short, that's "three" (3) entries that correspond to a "single document" in your collection that would be scanned for in the collection.

Of course that "filters down" considering your query criteria. So looking for `"f.t": "g"` here would mean "two" (2) Objects scanned.

That is essentially the difference between "Objects" and "Documents" with relation to what the query planner gives as output.

Note: There is a similar case with "Geospatial" type queries based on how the engine actually stores things and how they are retrieved when interacting with queries and explain output here that reports "similar" "document expansion" beyond the expected document count. But it's all just "Objects" in an index that are being treated this way.

So:

- `n` is "result" Documents
- `nScannedObjects` is Objects

Comment: Thanks! Very good insight. Do you know a book or article that deeps into index creation and scan procedures?

Comment: @borjagvo No resources I know of actually. Not published anyway, though there probably should be. Join a MongoDB User Group and then you might get a bit better access to information that is not generally published or at least a chance to interact with other people who use the product directly, where in both forms there is more chance of interacting with the core team and getting the information. Or just post questions here, where people do look.